# How to keep count of MAX SCORE or like a PERSONAL BEST SCORE in a little game

Tags: javascript

I've been following a codehs course in intro JS, I'm making a final project game. I'm making a game where the user can joggle the ball on the tennis racket in a nutshell and I want to keep track of the score. I've already figured the way to do a CURRENT SCORE thing, when the score shows the score of the current game. But, when the ball drops on the ground, the game finishes and the score restarts. I want to make a PERSONAL_BEST kind of score, which will be displayed on the screen and will just have the maximum amount of score that the user has managed to get and every time the user scores even higher, the max score should change to that as well. I have like 300 lines of code so I'm not sure if I should write it here, but any kind of advice would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: `maxScore = Math.max(currentScore, maxScore)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of a global variable for this, something like:

```
var HIGHEST_SCORE

if CURRENT_SCORE > HIGHEST_SCORE

   HIGHEST_SCORE = CURRENT_SCORE
```

Then just display the HIGHEST_SCORE nearby

Furthermore, If you want to track this value after you've played before, you could read and write this value into a local file